# A question on linear transformation(Projection)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the real field $\mathbb{R}$. Let $I$ denote the identity transformation of $V$. For which $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is it true that for every projection $P$ the transformation $P+cI$ is invertible?

Comment: I came across this problem while I read for entrance examination. Thank you for your cooperation in solving or giving hint.

Answer (score 3):

As $P$ is a projection, its eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$. So the eigenvalues of $P+cI$ are $c$ and $1+c$. Then the statement is true for any $c$ not equal to $0$ or $-1$.

Comment: Read the question again.

Comment: my apologies....

Comment: To make the one direction precise: If $c=0$, we can choose $P=0$ and if $c=-1$, we can choose $P=I$ to see that a specific choice of $P$ makes $P+cI=0$ non-invertible.  - However, some care should be taken for the exceptional case $\dim V=0$: In that case $P+cI$ happens to be invertible for *all* values of $c$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\dim V=0$, then any transformation (there is only one) is invertible, hence in that case any $c$ is allowed. Therefore, assume $\dim V>0$ from now on.

A projection is by definition a transformation $P$ with $P^2=P$.
If $c=0$, then $P=0$ is a projection and if $c=-1$ then $P=I$ is a projection with $P+cI=0$, which is not invertible.
Now consider $c\notin\{0,-1\}$ and let $P$ be a projection.
Then $(P+cI)v=0$ implies $0=P(P+cI)v=PPv+cPv=(1+c)Pv$, hence  $Pv=0$ because $1+c\ne0$. But then also $cv=Pv+cv=(P+cI)v=0$ and because of $c\ne 0$ finally $v=0$. We conclude that $P+cI$ has trivial kernel if $c\notin\{0,-1\}$. As $\dim V$ is finite, this implies that $P+cI$ is invertible.

In summary: If $\dim V=0$, then the statement is true for all $c\in\mathbb R$. If $\dim V>0$, the statement is true exactly for $c\notin\{0,-1\}$.